# How can I write a file from a drag'n dropped text within my RichTextbox control to the windows explorer?

Tags: c#, file-io, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I know the following question is a bit tricky, but I really need to solve it...

Imagine you have a form with a textbox-control (in my case a RichTextBox) on it. 
Now you select a portion of text within this control, start a drag-event and drop the selected text OUTSIDE the form, right to some folder within the windows explorer, as for instance the desktop...

How can this be accomplished? I didn't found something useful on the net besides the following link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1600192.aspx/1

All i know is that this kind of file-writing operation is called "scrap-file generation". 
Have someone a useful hint for me?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FileDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.filedrop.aspx) expects the files to exist and the drop just does a copy of the file. You will have to write your data out to a file and then pass that name to the DataObject.  The below is just a demonstration and you will need to figure out how you write the files and clean everything up so you are not creating extra files on the user's PC.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the left mouse button is down when leaving the rtb
    if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Write everything to a temp file.
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"z:\Temp\helloWorld.rtf", richTextBox1.SelectedRtf);
        string[] filenames = { @"z:\Temp\helloWorld.rtf" };
        DataObject obj = new DataObject();
        // Set the drag drop data with the FileDrop format
        obj.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, filenames);
        // Start the drag drop effect
        DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! I really didn't believed that it would be that easy !!! Thank you very much John ;-)